# Computing sums with linear conditions quickly

Tags: algorithms, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, computational-geometry, convolution

Let $f:\{1,\dotsc,N\}\to \mathbb{C}$, $\beta:\{1,\dotsc,N\}\to [0,1]$ be given by tables (or, what is basically the same, assume their values can be computed in constant time). For $0\leq \gamma_0\leq 1$, $0\leq \gamma_1\leq 1/N$, define
$$F(\gamma_0,\gamma_1) = \sum_{\stackrel{1\leq n\leq N}{\beta_n\leq \gamma_0+\gamma_1 n}} f(n).$$

Write $\tilde{O}(N)$ for "roughly $O(N)$", e.g., $O(N (\log N)^{O(1)})$.

Question 1. Is it possible to spend $\tilde{O}(N)$ time in some preparatory computations and then be able to compute $F(\gamma_0,\gamma_1)$ for any given $\gamma_0,\gamma_1$ as above in time $\tilde{O}(1)$?

(This would be the case if all it took were some initial sorting and/or FFT and/or what have you.  One can clearly do this for the special cases $F(\gamma_0,0)$ and $F(0,\gamma_1)$. That's weak reason for hope; I expect the answer to be most likely "no", though I have no idea of how one would prove it.)

Question 2. What about computing $\{F(a_m,m/N^2)\}_{1\leq m\leq N}$ for some given sequence $\{a_m\}_{1\leq n\leq N}$, $0\leq a_m\leq 1$? Can that be done in time $\tilde{O}(N)$?

A "yes" answer to Q1 would obviously imply a "yes" answer to Q2.

---

An informal description of this problem:

We start with a row of people of different heights on a horizontal platform, with each person $n$ having a certain number of dinars $f(n)$. We can ask ourselves how many dinars people with their heads under the water would have in total, for water level $=a_0$. Then we start to slowly tilt the platform, and ask ourselves: what happens for slope $=1/N^2$ and water level $=a_1$, for slope $=2/N^2$ and water level $=a_2$,..., and so up to slope $=1/N$ and water level $=a_N$? Can that be done in time $\tilde{O}(N)$?

(People here are holding their breath, not dying!)

Comment: The sets $\{n\mid\beta_n\le \gamma_0+\gamma_1 n\}$ can have at most $O(N^2)$ different values for given function $\beta$. You might get more feedback with a computational-geometry tag as algorithms for points in the plane are a big thing there.